# How to insert IDs from one table by matching them with multiple columns in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a complex SQL script that I can't quite get right. This is a summary of the issue: -

**OBJECTIVE**

- Data has been imported into the database via an Excel spreadsheet (Table B).
- A certain section of data on Table B (Nine columns from the table) has been inserted into Table A . This has generated database IDs for that section of data in Table A.
- I now want to take those newly generated IDs and re-insert them back into Table B, matching with the correct rows from the nine columns they originally came from.

**ISSUE**

- The issue I'm facing is that some of the data in Table B is not unique i.e. 2+ more rows in say the first column match with each other. This is the same for the other eight columns.
- In short there is no unique row in a single column to latch back onto when bringing the IDs back over.
- As such, when I'm bringing the IDs across from Table A into Table B via a simple UPDATE script, I'm occasionally getting the same ID inputted twice where it's matching on records that have the same data in them.

**REQUIREMENT**

- As I don't have a unique record to latch onto, is it possible for a script to consider multiple columns as the "unique record".
- To phrase this differently, I want to INSERT or UPDATE a New ID column in Table B, using the newly generated IDs from Table A, and match them by using multiple matching columns across both tables.

**REDUNDANT SCRIPT: -**

This script is likely redundant but it will provide some context for what was trying to be achieved, albeit with only using one column as the unique match, which is where the issue had been originally identified.

```
UPDATE b  
SET b.NewIDColumn = a.IDColumn  
FROM TableB b  
LEFT JOIN TableA a ON a.Column1 = REPLACE(b.Column1,'"','')  
WHERE b.Column1 IS NOT NULL AND b.Column1 <> '
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand this completely. You have copied partial rows (9 columns) from table B to table A. So, now there are as many rows in table A as in table B? But the nine columns are not unique. I can find two or more rows for the same combination of these 9 columns in the tables. Yes? And now you want to link the rows, such as with two rows for a combination in each table, you want one of the B rows to get the one A.id and the other B row the other A.id?

Comment: Some sample data illustrating what you describe would go a long way here.

Comment: What stops you from joining on all 9 columns between the two tables

Answer (score 0):

As [siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen) suggests in the comments, why not just join on all 9 columns you have in both tables (or any subset of those 9 columns you are confident is unique)?

```
update b  
set b.NewIDColumn = a.IDColumn  
from TableB b  
left join TableA a ON a.column1 = b.column1
                  and a.column2 = b.column2
                  and a.column3 = b.column3
                  and a.column4 = b.column4
                  and a.column5 = b.column5
                  and a.column6 = b.column6
                  and a.column7 = b.column7
                  and a.column8 = b.column8
                  and a.column9 = b.column9
```